# Comparing a 2 dimensional array to a single dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, comparison, 2d, multidimensional-array

Does anyone know why this doesn't compile?

```
public class ArrayCompare{

   public static void main (String []args){

      String words= "Hello this is a test";

      String delimiter=" ";
      String [] blocker=words.split(delimiter);

      String [][] grid= new String [100][100];

      grid[0]="Hello";

           if (grid[0].equals(blocker[0])){
                 System.out.print("Done!");
   }
        }
             }
```

I would like to perform this function of comparison using a 2 dimensional array. I am a newbie! Please help if you can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `grid[0]` is array of string. It is impossible to assign string to array of string.

Comment: Do you want to compare each String in grid to blocker[i]? If so, you need a nested loop

Comment: I wanted to test each String in grid to blocker[i].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grid[0][0]="Hello";
```

`grid` is a two-dimensional array. For the same reason, you need to do this:

```
if (grid[0][0].equals(blocker[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't compile because grid[0] is not String type.
It is String[] (Array) type. Variable `grid[0]` is actually pointing to a `String[100]` array.

You are attempting to assign a string "Hello" to an array by

`grid[0]="Hello";` statement.

If you want to assign a string to a location in `grid`, you must provide two index(s) - following is legal:

`grid[0][0]="Hello";`

May I suggest using [eclipse](http://eclipse.org) or [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) to edit your Java code? so that such basic errors are shown on real-time and explained well?

Comment: @user1299661, if an answer was helpful, consider upvote (arrow on left) or accepting the answer - that will improve your chances of getting questions answered in SO in future.

Answer (score 0):

`grid[0]` is a `String[]` type, not a `String`. So your code should be like this

```
grid[0] = new String[100];
grid[0][0] = "Hello";
if (grid[0][0].equals(bloker[0])) {
    //your logic...
}
```

Comment: "grid[0][0] == bloker[0]" No! Don't do this! This is comparing references, which will not be equal. You need to use grid[0][0].equals(blocker[0]). This is true in general in Java.

Comment: But that's extremely bad practice, it shouldn't be shown to a newbie especially, and not true in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [][] grid= new String [100][100];

  grid[0]="Hello";
```

There's your problem. You are trying to assign a string to a string array. Think of a 2d array as an array of arrays.

You probably want something like

```
grid[0][0]="Hello!";
```

Answer (score 0):

grid is 2d array. you can't do like d[0] = "Hello". So, if you want to assign value at 0 position

```
d[0][0] = "Hello";

 if (grid[0][0].equals(blocker[0])){
System.out.print("Done!");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can't assign value to the element of the multi dimensional array using single index

grid[0]="Hello";
you need to specify both the indices like grid[0][0] = "Hello"
this will set the 0th element of 0th row to Hello

Likewise while compairing 
           if (grid[0].equals(blocker[0])){ 
                 System.out.print("Done!"); 
you have to pass the same indices here (You cannot compare a String to a Array Object)
  if (grid[0][0].equals(blocker[0])){ 
      System.out.print("Done!");